# how to close showModal() when someone click outside

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I implemented a functionality of JS show Modal() and I want to close it when someone click outside the popup means on document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the dialog-content in a div with `padding: 0`. This way you can check for `event.target` of the click-event, which references the dialog in case of backdrop and any other element within the div in case of the actual modal.

```html
<button onclick="this.nextElementSibling.showModal()">Open Dialog</button>

<dialog style="padding: 0" onclick="event.target==this && this.close()">
  <form style="margin: 0; padding: 1rem">
    <p>Clicking the inner area doesn't close the dialog</p>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: This is works exactly what i wanted but the problem is when the page gets loaded the background screen remains blur. So the basic idea is when someone click outside the popup the popup should be gone which is worked thanks, but the blur background needs to be remove as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer with running code snippet. The blurred background that appears with the popup dialog should disappear automatically when the dialog is closed. (Please run and check the updated snippet.)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

```
  <!-- pop-up dialog box, containing a form -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
    <form method="dialog">
        <p>
            <label for="favAnimal">Favorite animal:</label>
            <select id="favAnimal" name="favAnimal">
                <option></option>
                <option>Brine shrimp</option>
                <option>Red panda</option>
                <option>Spider monkey</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <div>
            <button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</dialog>

<div>
    <button id="updateDetails">Update details</button>
</div>

<script>
    const updateButton = document.getElementById("updateDetails");
    const cancelButton = document.getElementById("cancel");
    const dialog = document.getElementById("favDialog");
    dialog.returnValue = "favAnimal";

    function openCheck(dialog) {
        if (dialog.open) {
            console.log("Dialog open");
        } else {
            console.log("Dialog closed");
        }
    }

    // Update button opens a modal dialog
    updateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        dialog.showModal();
        openCheck(dialog);
    });

    // Form cancel button closes the dialog box
    cancelButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        dialog.close("animalNotChosen");
        openCheck(dialog);
    });
 //close showModal() when someone click outside
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == dialog) {
            dialog.close("animalNotChosen");
            openCheck(dialog);
        }}
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I can't understand how it is closing when someone clicked outside there is no as such function to close when someone clicked outside. Can you please explain ?

Comment: @shubham maini  The bootstrap modal plugin toggles your hidden content on request, using data attributes or JavaScript. It additionally adds .modal-open to the `<body>` to override default scrolling behavior and creates a .modal-backdrop to implement a click area for dismissing shown modals when clicking outside the bootstrap modal.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap i am using JS showModal() method

Comment: @shubham maini Do you want something like my update?

Comment: Not really, good for bootstrap but not sure for js

Comment: @shubham maini It's sure for js, you can have a try.